# Workflow 2013 for SP Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016, workflow-manager

First off I'm kind of new to SP Admin work.  I'm trying to get 2013 w/f in Designer (this is a 2016 Farm w/eval Enterprise license).  successfully installed Web Platform Installer, Workflow Manager 1.0 and Cumulative Update 3.  when I try to run the "Register" command from PS (as Admin) I don't have an option for "-SPWorkflowService"  It seems I have no options for SPWorkflow no matter the command i.e. "Get", "New"

I noticed there is a "Workflow Service Application" but no Proxy under it, seems there should be?[image]

Answer (score 3):

As the reported PowerShell error "**The term is not recognized"**, you are using `Windows Powershell`, not `SharePoint management shell`.

In `Windows Powershell`, before running the SharePoint cmdlet, you should add `SharePoint Snapin` as the following

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

> Also, make sure that you have installed the **Workflow Manager
>   Client** on each SharePoint Cross the farm.

**Check also**

- [REGISTER-SPWORKFLOWSERVICE](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/12/register-spworkflowservice-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-service/)
- [How to check the Workflow manager connectivity](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/)